# Programmatically create a simple org entry?

Tags: org-mode

Is there a predefined function to create a simple org entry? (Writing it with `insert` would work but wondered if there was a better way.)

`(create "heading" '("tag1" "tag2" "tag3") "plain text\ncontent here" '(("some_key" "some_value")))`

would create this:

```
* heading          :tag1:tag2:tag3:
:PROPERTIES:
:some_key:    some_value
:END:

plain text
content here
```

What I've already tried:

- `org-entry-put` works for properties of existing entries
- [here](https://orgmode.org/worg/dev/org-element-api.html) it says that `org-element-interpret-data` is supposed to help me but can't quite figure out how that works

Comment: It's perhaps a failure of imagination on my part, but why would you want this? IMO&E, if it's a one-off type of document, I type it in. If it's a templated kind with some limited interaction, I use `org-capture`. BTW, you probably want to give `org-element-interpret-data` and friends a wide berth, at least at the beginning: there is a very wide gulf between what it does and what you are (or at least seem to be) describing above. You might consider adding a "user story" to your question.

Answer (score 2):

This answer combines the ideas above. There are other templated approaches you might take too where you directly construct the heading/tags. There isn't a way I could see where you only use org-element-interpret-data though, that does not seem to handle the properties or content. that is why they are treated separately here.

```
(defun create-heading (level title tags content properties)
  (when (not (bolp)) (insert "\n"))
  (insert (org-element-interpret-data
       `(headline (:title ,title :tags ,tags :level ,level))))
  (cl-loop for (key val) in properties do (org-entry-put (point) key val))
  (insert content))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for something simple, then `insert` is probably the way to go. There are various [org specific insert functions](https://orgmode.org/manual/Command-and-Function-Index.html) that could help simplify things.

For something more general, or something not easily written as a [capture template](https://orgmode.org/manual/Capture-templates.html), the [Org Element API](https://orgmode.org/worg/dev/org-element-api.html) could be useful. It works on the AST of an org file or org-mode buffer. e.g. use `org-element-parse-buffer` and manipulate the AST directly (or use `org-element-insert-before` or...) and then `org-element-interpret-data` to render the changes.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do this with `org-capture-template`. If you have set up the global keybindings as the manual suggests, you should be able to type `C-c c C` to enter the interactive customizer, and from there you can define a template. If not, you can always use the more verbose `M-x org-capture C`.

See [Capture templates](https://orgmode.org/manual/Capture-templates.html) in the manual.